# How can I distinguish two images having coordinate of object?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, biometrics

I am using OpenCV with c++ and I have several images with located minutiae (end/branch). 
Minutiae have:coordinate(x,y) , type(end/branch) and angle.
How can distinguish one image from another having this information??
I need very simple algorithm or code or any idea!!!
Example with located points:
http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/minucjepn_xhaqnwh.png/
How can I distinguish images with thats located points??

Comment: It doesn't really matter how urgent your question is(!!!!!!!), nobody is going to answer it without more detail. You need to show what you've attempted so far.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) might help, although I can provide more specific information only if I know more about the problem.

Comment: This is example of my result:
http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/minucjepn_xhaqnwh.png/
I cant use SURF or SIFT. I have to use any relation beetwenn coordinate and type of minutiae!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [geometric hashing](https://www.google.com/search?q=geometric%20hashing).

Answer (score 0):

@user1666649, this is not as simple as you told. If you  look for scientific articles, there are many of Bologne University about this. If you need a semple code you can look for NBIS from NIST/FBI. However if you are looking a good algorithm, you will need to buy a commercial one from Veridis, Neurotechnology, Aware, etc...